# print only works when it wants too. I need to know why

Tags: python, printing

Below is all the coding. At the last section where the functions interact with one another the print welcome to tic tac toe and which player goes first does not print. How and why? Indents are actually as they should be, bringing it over to stackoverflow did not bring over the indents. All functions work. Don't have an issue with them. Just want to understand why the last cell the two print statements welcome to tic tac toe and who goes first does not work at all. restarted kernel retyped them, deleted the cell copy and pasted. no clue how to make it print.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
def run_board(board):
clear_output()
print(' '+board[7]+' | '+board[8]+' | '+board[9]+' ')
print(' ~   ~   ~')
print(' '+board[4]+' | '+board[5]+' | '+board[6]+' ')
print(' ~   ~   ~')
print(' '+board[1]+' | '+board[2]+' | '+board[3]+' ')

def choose_marker():
marker=''

while not(marker=='X' or marker=='O'):
    marker = input('Player 1 choose X or O ').upper()
    
if marker=='X':
    return('X','O')
else:
    return('O','X')

def place_marker(board,marker,position):
board[position]=marker

def win_check(board,marker):
return ((board[1]==marker and board[2]==marker and board[3]==marker)or
       (board[4]==marker and board[5]==marker and board[6]==marker)or
       (board[7]==marker and board[8]==marker and board[9]==marker)or
       (board[7]==marker and board[4]==marker and board[1]==marker)or
       (board[8]==marker and board[5]==marker and board[2]==marker)or
       (board[9]==marker and board[6]==marker and board[3]==maker)or
       (board[7]==marker and board[5]==marker and board[3]==marker)or
       (board[9]==marker and board[5]==marker and board[1]==marker))

def spot_check(board,position):
return board[position]==' '

def full_board_check(board):
for pos in range(1,10):
    if spot_check(board,pos):
        return False
return True

def pick_spot(board):
position=0
while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not spot_check(board,position):
    position= int(input('Pick a location per num keys far right.'))
return position

import random
def go_first():
if random.randint(0,1)==0:
    return 'Player 1'
else:
    return 'Player 2'


def play_again():
return input('Do you want to play again? Yes or No.').lower().startswith('y')
```

**now the section Where it all goes into one cell and the print does not work:**

```
print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe')

while True:
game_board=[' ']*10
turn=go_first()
print(turn+' Will go first')
run_board(game_board)
player1,player2=choose_marker()
play_game=input('Are you Ready to play?').lower()
if play_game[0]=='y':
    game_on=True
else:
    game_on=False

while game_on:
    if turn=='Player 1':
        run_board(game_board)
        position=pick_spot(game_board)
        place_marker(game_board,player1,position)
        
        if win_check(game_board,player1):
            run_board(game_board)
            print('You won MF')
            game_on=False
        else:
            if full_board_check(game_board):
                run_board(game_board)
                print('Wow you both lost. Nice.')
                game_on=False
            else:
                turn='Player 2'
    elif turn=='Player 2':
        run_board(game_board)
        position=pick_spot(game_board)
        place_marker(game_board,player2,position)
        
        if win_check(game_board,player2):
            run_board(game_board)
            print('You won even though you went last')
            game_on=False
        else:
            if full_board_check(game_board):
                run_board(game_board)
                print('Wow you both lost')
                game_on=False
            else:
                turn='Player 1'
if not play_again():
    break
```

Comment: While I appreciate that you mentioned your code has indentation issues when pasting into stack overflow, it's unreasonable for us to try and help debug your program unless we can see the actual indentation. Consider using three backticks (`\`\`\``) at the beginning and end of your code in order to format it without having to change the indentation when pasting into Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does print what you want it to, but then you clear it away. For example it prints Welcome to Tic Tac Toe but then you run run_board which clears it away. I deleted run_board from the initial while loop and that solved the problem you originally posted about.

However, I ran into 2 other minor issues. I fixed those and posted it below. Don't look at the code below if you are doing this for learning and want to try solving it yourself first, but it's there if you want it.

```
print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe')
game_on=False
while game_on==False:
    game_board=[' ']*10
    turn=go_first()
    print(turn+' Will go first')
    player1,player2=choose_marker()
    play_game=input('Are you Ready to play?').lower()
    if play_game[0]=='y':
        game_on=True
    else:
        game_on=False

while game_on:
    if turn=='Player 1':
        run_board(game_board)
        position=pick_spot(game_board)
        place_marker(game_board,player1,position)
        
        if win_check(game_board,player1):
            run_board(game_board)
            print('You won MF')
            game_on=False
        else:
            if full_board_check(game_board):
                run_board(game_board)
                print('Wow you both lost. Nice.')
                game_on=False
            else:
                turn='Player 2'
    elif turn=='Player 2':
        run_board(game_board)
        position=pick_spot(game_board)
        place_marker(game_board,player2,position)
        
        if win_check(game_board,player2):
            run_board(game_board)
            print('You won even though you went last')
            game_on=False
        else:
            if full_board_check(game_board):
                run_board(game_board)
                print('Wow you both lost')
                game_on=False
            else:
                turn='Player 1'
    if game_on==False:
        if not play_again():
            break
```

Comment: OMG. I forgot about the clear. We just went over that. So I would of never considered it as a possibility. Was driving me crazy. Thank you so much.